# Customize node add page

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, theming

I created a content type in Drupal 7 "test" with the following fields:

- Title;
- Body;
- Image;
- Tag (taxonomy tagging)

I would like to customize the node creation page, by inserting the tag field function jQuery

```
<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Insert Tag" class="tm-input tm-input-warning tm-input-small"/>
<script>
jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager();
</script>
```

The file name is `page--node--add--test.tpl.php`.

Where do I insert the jQuery code?

Comment: Basically you want to substitute Drupal's autocomplete with your own?

Comment: you want to insert this http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

Comment: have you tried https://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe

Comment: Any reason to use custom code here, instead of Drupal-provided tag field?